# How to make Vert.x and Apache Ignite Client work together?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, ignite, vert.x

I deployed Apache Ignite cluster and I need to perform different operations with caches from my Vert.x backend.
I successfully connect to cluster using Apache Ignite client (not Thin client). Apache Ingite Client is run inside Vert.x verticle:

```java
 vertx.deployVerticle(new IgniteVerticle(),
                    new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(1).setWorker(true),
                    apacheIgniteVerticleDeployment.completer());
```

But some time later I start receiving the following messages:

```
SEVERE: Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. 
This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour  [threadName=tcp-comm-worker, blockedFor=28s]

SEVERE: Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler 
[hnd=NoOpFailureHandler [super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=[SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED,
 err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=tcp-comm-worker, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1567112815022]]]
```

```java
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=tcp-comm-worker, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1567112815022]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance$2.apply(IgnitionEx.java:1831)  at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance$2.apply(IgnitionEx.java:1826)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.worker.WorkersRegistry.onIdle(WorkersRegistry.java:233)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.onIdle(GridWorker.java:297)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.timeout.GridTimeoutProcessor$TimeoutWorker.body(GridTimeoutProcessor.java:221)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Such messages appear about every 10 seconds. I have a guess that this can be somehow related to the way how Vert.x works.

What can be the reason of these exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing `systemWorkerBlockedTimeout` on `IgniteConfiguration` to make this message go away. See more in docs:
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/critical-failures-handling